# hibernate lazy initialization issue

Tags: hibernate

I am new to hibernate. Can anyone please assist me with following

My application uses spring and hibernate. In hbm.xml file I am using lazy=true and fetch=join.

I have 10000 Parent objects which I'm iterating using a for loop. Inside the for loop I am calling the child objects by doing parent.toString();
toString is overridden.

This process of calling the child objects is taking lots of time, as it executes many select queries from child objects. Is there any way I can optimize this.

Comment: I have tried different fetch and also tried making lazy=false but results were slow

Comment: I think you can optimize it, yes, but at least for me it is a bit difficult to assess, also to propose an alternative, if you don't post any code... Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Never fire query inside loop Instead you can get all child of all the parents by following the below steps.

Create a method in Hibernate DAO and pass the join property in the function OR you can send array of joinproperties  Eg:

```
 public findAllRecord(Class persistentClass, String joinproperty)   // For array (String[] joinproperty)
    {
        Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(persistentClass);        criteria.setResultTransformer(CriteriaSpecification.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
        criteria.setFetchMode(joinproperty, FetchMode.JOIN);
        return criteria.list();
    }
```

You can add restriction in above critera like :

// Add your criteria restriction here and you can pass the the property in the above function also eg:

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq(propertyName, name));
```

The above name and propertyName you can pass through function dynamically.

Now call the above method by passing your join property;
Eg:

```
class Parent{

  private int id;
  private String name;
  private Child child;

}

class Child{

   // Child property
}
```

The method call will be....like.

```
String joinproperty="child";  // Property of Parent class which you want to join
findAllRecord(Parent.class, String joinproperty)
```

Hope this will  help you out...